# Convert pdf document to jpeg using LEADTOOLS and PDF-TOOLS

Tags: pdf, dpi, leadtools-sdk

We have pdf documents (source: camera or scanner) that we want to convert to jpeg.
We use LEADTOOLS and PDF-TOOLS(in two separate programs) to convert these pdf files to jpeg files.
Both these tools use the default DPI of 150 irrespective of the DPI of the source pdf file.
We would rather like this value to be taken from the source pdf file.
For example: Adobe Acrobat software recognizes the source pdf file DPI and uses the same to create the jpeg file.

Is there some way we could achieve the same using the LEADTOOLS and PDF-TOOLS by determining the DPI of the source pdf file?

Comment: Sounds like you want image extraction, not document conversion.

Answer (score 1):

This feature was added to v19 of LEADTOOLS a few months ago. You can now extract images from PDF pages while preserving their original pixel dimensions using the following members of the Leadtools.Pdf.PDFDocument class:

- ParseDocumentStructure method.
- Images property.
- DecodeImage method.

Furthermore, if the image is stretched inside the PDF page, you can detect that by examining its display size in the PDF page using the Leadtools.Pdf.PDFObject.Bounds property.
There's a dedicated demo for the PDFDocument class and related objects installed with LEADTOOLS 19 in these folders:

- Examples\DotNet\CS\PDFDocumentDemo
- Examples\DotNet\VB\PDFDocumentDemo